# Difference in execution time for a command between bash script and console - error in script?

Tags: bash, curl

I did a script bash to perform several "curl" actions. I noticed that there is a huge difference when I execute the same curl command through the script or directly in the console.

```
execution time for curl through bash script: 56 sec
execution time for curl directly from console (same command): 1 sec
```

Is there an error in my script (e.g., the way the command is written)?
Here my bash script:

```
NUM_USER=0
NUM_RUNS=0

while [ $NUM_RUNS -le 0 ]
do
    while [ $NUM_USER -le 2 ]
    do
        sleep 0.5
        start_time=`date +%s`
        curl --proxy http://10.0.20.89:8080 --proxy-negotiate http://10.0.3.50 -u : --negotiate > /dev/null 2>&1
        end_time=`date +%s`
        echo execution time was `expr $end_time - $start_time` s
        NUM_USER=`expr $NUM_USER + 1`
        sleep 30
    done
    NUM_RUNS=`expr $NUM_RUNS + 1`
done
```

Comment: The only thing that could plausibly explain such a difference is the web request, with a difference in what gets exchanged over the network. The very first thing to do is to log the output from curl instead of discarding it, and post the output. Check that the environment variables are the same in the two contexts, especially `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, etc. Do make sure that your script is executed by bash (a bash script must start with `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or similar, although execution by another mostly-compatible shell wouldn't explain such a huge difference.

Comment: I forgot to write it here, but yes the script begins with the line  #!/bin/bash  The output is the same from console or script. I added the output redirection to null in order to speed up the process (without any result)

Comment: You can also use tcpdump to see the request.The script looks ok.

Comment: John Zeng thanks, using tcpdump I discovered that, using the script, dns queries are performed. I still don't understand why, since the command directly trhough console does not perform/require any dns request

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer doing a tcpdump of the packets in both cases.
In summary, using the script, a dns is performed to resolve addresses (not needed) and this causes the delay. Directly through console those dns requests are not present.
At the end the result of the command is the same.